# selecting a div inside another div using $(this)

Tags: jquery, select, html

Sorry for this absolute newbie question. It's a super easy question, but I'm having no luck the last couple of hours on getting this to work. (just started with jQuery)

I'm trying to animate a div when you rollover a hit-zone div. 
(I made the hit-zone div because the top div with the text is going to be animated as well)

jQuery:

```
$(".hitzone").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent("#teal_rollover").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, 400, 'swing');   
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio_item1">              
    <div id="background_img"><img src="geof17/cat.png" /></div> 
    <div id="teal_rollover"><img src="geof17/teal_rollover.png" /></div>
    <div id="portfolio_tem_cat1_tekst">poessie <br />illustratie </div> 
    <div class="hitzone"></div> 
</div>
```

I'm not able to select the div with the id teal_rollover.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$(this).parent().find("#teal_rollover").animate(....);
```

Comment: i'm building a statue in your honor!

Comment: @user1158901 thanx; but in which location?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sibling` instead of `parent`?

Answer (score 1):

`.hitzone` is not a child of `#teal_rollover`, it's a sibling.  You can either use the `.sibling()` selector, or since `teal_rollover` is an ID anyway, you can just use that selector without getting more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The `#teal_rollover` div is not a parent of `.hitzone`.

Try this:

```
$(".hitzone").mouseover(function(){
    $("#teal_rollover").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, 400, 'swing');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally ids shuold be unique on a page so you can directly use id selector `$("#teal_rollover")`.

```
$(".hitzone").mouseover(function(){
    $("#teal_rollover").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, 400, 'swing');   
});
```

In case you have cannot have unique ids then I would suggest you to remove the id attribute and give a class. You can then use class selector using `siblings` method to find the corresponding element and animate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since teal_rollover is an ID, you can just use

`$("#teal_rollover").animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, 400, 'swing');`

Incase if you really want to access through parent element then you can do,

```
$(this).siblings('#teal_rollover').animate({ opacity: 0.75 }, 400, 'swing');
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique on a page so you can just use `$("#teal_rollover")`.

In fact, selecting just by ID will have better performance than using things like `parent` and `siblings`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using prevUntil rather than parent because #teal_rollover is not a parent of hitzone, it is a sibling.

http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/